# UILabel first letter lowercase

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm trying to set the first letter of a `UILabel` to lowercase, but can't find answers that could help me. I would like to solve this problem without editing the original content.

Something like this is possible?

```
 myLabel.text.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
```

Or i must make the `NSString`'s (that holds the content) first letter to lowercase before i pass it to the label?

**UPDATE:**

As Nikolas said it's not possible with the `UILabel`, edit the string to solve the problem.

Comment: (Note that autocapitalizaton only applies to keyboard input, not text you supply.)

Comment: @HotLicks  I think it can be good too, if i could turn off the first character is uppercase function on the keyboard. It was my first plan. It must be done with code or it's possible with interface builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once was had the same issue, so I was very thoroughly scanning the [docs of `UILabel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html), but I didn't find an option that would allow achieving this on the level of the `UILabel`-API so I also ended up modifying the resulting `NSString`, so I guess that's not possible.

Putting the modifications into a cateogry for `UILabel` (`UILabel+Capitalization.h`) in the end worked quite well for me, so that every time the label was modified I could call something like:
`[label capitalize]` was quite convenient. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Nikolas, you saved me some time, because i thought that's possible so i can stop trying it with the label. I'll go with the edit string version.